# pagination more than 1 table

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

i want to make pagination on ci from other web reference, but average of them use only 1 table
does anyone know how to input  more than 1 table on this condition

```
public function data($number,$offset){
    return $query = $this->db->get('client',$number,$offset)->result();         
}
```

i have try to input like this

```
public function data($number,$offset){
    return $query = $this->db->get('client,advertisement,size',$number,$offset)->result();          
}
```

but the result is  not my expected

[image]

the NAMA is looping, the IKLAN too but the SIZE is not

i take the refences from [here](https://www.malasngoding.com/cara-membuat-pagination-pada-codeigniter/)

Comment: ahahha, forget about that. i use join sql to select all table. make sure there is an relation between table 1 and the other one

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
public function fetch_countries($limit, $start) {
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->join('client', 'advertisement.id_client= client.id_client','inner');
    $this->db->join('size', 'advertisement.id_size= size.id_size','inner');
    $query = $this->db->get("advertisement");

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: very funny if I asked, the next day I answered LOL